# Multiple lines in D3 line graph (rollup data)

Tags: d3.js

I want to put multiple lines on a single graph. I started with a standard CSV dataset that I aggregated using `d3.nest()` and `.rollup()`.

Using the best way I know how, I performed a for-loop over the first level of keys then plotted the second level of keys and values. My code outputted the correct number of lines but the Y- and X-axes scales were off. The expected output is one graph with 3 lines that are all scaled correctly.

EDIT: A peer let me know that the error is likely due to the scales. After console logging the values, they would appear to cause the issue. I moved the `x` and `y.domain` outside of the for-loop and it helped with the scale but the lines were still not displaying properly.

Note that in the code example I pre-formatted the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/d3-dsv.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body></body>

</script>
<script>
  var margin = {top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var colorArray = [d3.schemeCategory10][0]

  var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 50)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  dataAgg = [
    {"key": 2015, "values": [
      {key: "3", value: 1}, {key: "4", value: 19},
      {key: "5", value: 176}, {key: "6", value: 524},
      {key: "7", value: 284}, {key: "8", value: 31}]
    },
    {"key": 2016, "values": [
      {key: "3", value: 1}, {key: "4", value: 10},
      {key: "5", value: 88}, {key: "6", value: 497},
      {key: "7", value: 410}, {key: "8", value: 72},
      {key: "9", value: 3}]
    },
    {"key": 2017, "values": [
      {key: "6", value: 28}, {key: "7", value: 78},
      {key: "8", value: 52}, {key: "9", value: 8}]
    },
  ]

  var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.key); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

  for (i = 0; i < dataAgg.length; i++) {
    yData = dataAgg[i].values
    yData.sort(function(a, b) { return +a.key  - +b.key })
    color = colorArray[i]

    x.domain(d3.extent(yData, function(d) { return d.key; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(yData, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    svg.append("path")
        .data([yData])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline)
        .attr('stroke', color)
  }

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by taking the `x` and `y.domain` lines outside of the for-loop and editing them slightly to make them more dynamic:

```
  x.domain(d3.extent(dataAgg.map(d => d.values).flat(), v => v.key));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(dataAgg.map(d => d.values).flat(), v => v.value)]);
```